# HAProxy backend/server to specific destination using SSL and SNI returns "OpenSSL error[0x14094410] ssl3_read_bytes: sslv3 alert handshake failure"

Tags: server, openssl, backend, haproxy, sni

I have set up a HAProxy-instance that should:

- offload SSL on the frontend
- onload SSL on the backend
- use SNI for the connections and the healthchecks towards the upstreams

For this demonstration I created a shortened HAProxy-configuration looking like this:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1 local0
        maxconn 8000
        user nobody
        group nogroup
        daemon
        debug
        #quiet
        stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3
        ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
        log global
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option dontlognull
        option abortonclose
        option redispatch
        retries 3
        maxconn 18000
        timeout connect 30s
        timeout client 30s
        timeout server 30s


frontend test.local
        bind 0.0.0.0:8443
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        option forwardfor

        acl api_statusio path_beg -i /status/1.0
        use_backend api_statusio if api_statusio

backend api_statusio
        option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ letsencrypt.status.io
        http-request set-header Host letsencrypt.status.io
        server test2 143.204.101.51:443 ssl check ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt sni str(letsencrypt.status.io) check-ssl check-sni str(letsencrypt.status.io)
```

This works for example using google.com as an upstream, but with no status.io-resource (letsencrypt.status.io is just an example here):

```
root@edc5cab629ae:/# haproxy -f ./haproxy.cfg 
[WARNING] 274/160954 (2642) : parsing [./haproxy.cfg:37] : The 'reqadd' directive is deprecated in favor of 'http-request add-header' and will be removed in next version.
[WARNING] 274/160954 (2642) : <debug> mode incompatible with <quiet> and <daemon>. Keeping <debug> only.
Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
Total: 3 (2 usable), will use epoll.

Available filters :
    [SPOE] spoe
    [COMP] compression
    [CACHE] cache
    [TRACE] trace
Using epoll() as the polling mechanism.
fd[0013] OpenSSL error[0x14094410] ssl3_read_bytes: sslv3 alert handshake failure
[WARNING] 274/160955 (2642) : Server api_statusio/test2 is DOWN, reason: Socket error, info: "SSL handshake failure", check duration: 111ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 274/160955 (2642) : backend 'api_statusio' has no server available!
fd[0014] OpenSSL error[0x14094410] ssl3_read_bytes: sslv3 alert handshake failure
fd[0014] OpenSSL error[0x14094410] ssl3_read_bytes: sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

If I use openssl s_client as a quick check, this seems to work fine.

This was tested with:

- HAProxy 2.0.3 + OpenSSL 1.1.1c 28 May 2019 (Docker haproxy:latest as of today)
- HAProxy 1.8.8 + OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018 (Ubuntu 18.04)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A friendly user on freenode #haproxy pointed out that

```
        server test2 143.204.101.51:443 ssl check ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt sni str(letsencrypt.status.io) check-ssl check-sni str(letsencrypt.status.io)
```

should be

```
        server test2 143.204.101.51:443 ssl check ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt sni str(letsencrypt.status.io) check-ssl check-sni letsencrypt.status.io
```

This works. After solving this I hit a similar problem with using server-template with multiple upstreams, which is described here: https://git.haproxy.org/?p=haproxy-2.0.git;a=commit;h=21944019cabcb46ceb95b7fd925528b9dace4e35 (but this is a different topic)